# Where can I find the Sunday Without God light novels in English?

Tags: sunday-without-god

Just as the title asks, where can I find the Sunday Without God light novels?  The anime lacked some detail and plot that I feel it needed, but I can't find the English translations anywhere.  If there isn't an official one, could you give me a fan translated one or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no licensed English translation of the *Sunday Without God* light novels. There probably never will be, since the show and the light novels are at best moderately popular in Japan.

Site policy is to not link to fan translations, so I'm just going to wink in the general direction of Google. (But you're not going to find much - the fans don't appear to be interested enough to translate the novels either.)

Comment: Would you be able to find me the sales of the ln and the anime separately or tell me where/how to find them?  It would be much appreciated!

Comment: @BradWhoville For the anime, see [here](http://www.someanithing.com/index.php?s=kami-sama+no+inai+nichiyoubi) and click through the various weekly sales lists (all volumes sold <1000, which is almost certainly below break-even). I don't think the light novels have ever charted, so I don't have sales figures - but the fact that they've never charted says something.